# getting text inside <a> tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp-2.1

```
<td id="unassignedUsers" class="userList">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { ?>
<a href="#" draggable="true" ondrop="(alert('hi!'))" ><?php echo $arrayusers[$i]['User']['fullname']; ?> </a>
<?php } ?>
```

After inserting draggable tags into the lost, I need to capture the text from each tag that has been dragged into the list.  This event should be triggered by a button click.

What is a good way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: If the problem is on the clinet, show the client code, not your PHP source code.

Comment: On clicking *what* button? Where is it, in relation to the `a` elements? Is there *one* button for *all* links, or one button *per* link?

Comment: the problem is not on the client, i am working with cakephp and in my view i have 4 lists (1:unassignedUsers, 2:moderators, 3:editors, 4:Jeditors) at the beginning the unassignedUsers list will contain all the users in my system then the admin will assign some of them to his position through dragging and dropping the press a button to save the changes he made...... then i need to have the names from the 3 lists (moderators,editors,jeditors) and insert them to the database...... i dont know how to do this and um searching for 2 days....

Comment: only one button for all links...

Comment: If it's server-side, then your question has nothing to do with JavaScript (JS, with the exception of [nodejs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs), is exclusively client-side). If your problem is with JavaScript, then it's a client-side problem. Now, if there's *one* button for *all* links, you want to get the text-content of *all* links (or just all unassignedUSers links?), and do what with that content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the text from the anchors with the `unassignedUsers` element:

```
var links_list = [];
var links = document.getElementById('unassignedUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var a in links) {
   if(typeof links[a] == undefined) continue;
   links_list.push(links[a].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: @karimgoda this is by no means a complete script - you will need to add to it ... and test it ...

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, How can i loop on this linked_list and get every value in a variable....

Comment: i got what i need by calling the toString() method on the linked list but it is printed as a comma separated values i need to loop on them and get every value in a variable...

Comment: @karimgoda instead of `alert()` use `for() {` to iterate of the array -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods